# Catch `concurrent update` error in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, isolation-level

Assume I created a function that I execute in [`REPEATABLE_READ`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html) isolation level in PostgresSQL, e.g.

`CREATE FUNCTION some_stuff() RETURNS void AS $$
 BEGIN 
      -- do stuff that could throw an error
 END;
 $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;`

It's possible for this function internally to throw the following error:
`ERROR:  could not serialize access due to concurrent update`. Is there a way to catch this error and repeat the function/transaction internally?
So have something like this:

`CREATE FUNCTION some_stuff() RETURNS void AS $$
 BEGIN 
    try {
      -- do stuff that could throw an error
    } catch (error) { call some_stuff(); }
 END;
 $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;`

Or has this error catching to be done in the application level, i.e. in Java that is calling this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's possible for this function internally to throw the following error: `ERROR: could not serialize access due to concurrent update`. Is there a way to catch this error and repeat the function/transaction internally?

No, it is not.

PostgreSQL's functions are implicitly wrapped in a transaction if one isn't already in progress. There is no way to obtain a new transaction snapshot from within a function in `repeatable read` or `serializable` isolation. You can't rollback and begin a new transaction.

For this to work PostgreSQL would need to support top-level procedures with autonomous commit.

You must have the controlling code on a separate connection. This means doing it from a client, or (ab)using `dblink` for the purpose.

Comment: about this: `are implicitly wrapped in a transaction if one isn't already in progress.`. Does this mean that if we have two functions `A` and `B` and function `A` internally calls `B` then there is only one transaction (created for the execution of `A`) and that the execution of `B` (when called by `A`) is being done inside this single transaction?

Comment: @foobar Correct. Nested transactions are possible (begin/except blocks, subtransactions) but not autonomous commit or transaction suspend/resume.